# Setting Default Session Provider to Environment Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web-config

I have an environment variable in my web.config file like `<add key="ConnectionString" value=""/>` that is pulled from the server when the application is published.

My session state is set up like this in the web config file

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" timeout="120" cookieless="false">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="" />
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

How can I set the connectionStringName to use the environment variable? I don't want to store the connection string in plain text in the web config file.

Comment: *"I don't want to store the connection string in plain text in the web config file."* but you already have it here in plain text here `<add key="ConnectionString" value="HERE"/>`

Comment: The value is left blank and comes from the server

Answer (score 0):

in web.config:

`<add name="MyConStr" connectionString="Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={2};Password={3}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

in programming code:

```
string strConnection = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConStr"]
                        .ConnectionString, "MyServerName", "MyDataBaseName", "MyUserName", "MyPassword");
```